# Microsoft.Maui.Platform.HandlerNotFoundException: 'Handler not found for view Maui.GoogleMaps.Map.'

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, maui, multiplatform

I am trying to put google maps on my application , I installed package onion.Maui.GoogleMaps , the problem is that package is only supported by android and ios and while I'm building mobile app it's good , but I keep getting errors from other platforms like mac and specifically Microsoft, because of using package which is not supported by them .
I tried to avoid the errors in program.cs by using :

```
 #if ANDROID || IOS
    using Maui.GoogleMaps.Hosting; // Include this only for Android and iOS
    #endif
```

but I don't know how avoid it in xaml.cs , or is it possible to specify the platforms of the project? like i want to work only on ios and android .
this the xaml folder :

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.NewPage3"
              xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Maui.GoogleMaps;assembly=Maui.GoogleMaps"
             Title="NewPage3"
             >

    <maps:Map x:Name="mymap"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</ContentPage>"
```

and this is the xaml.cs file :
"

```
using Maui.GoogleMaps;


namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class NewPage3 : ContentPage
{
    public NewPage3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

"
this the detials of the error "

> Microsoft.Maui.Platform.HandlerNotFoundException   Message=Handler not
> found for view Maui.GoogleMaps.Map.   Source=Microsoft.Maui
> StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view,
> IMauiContext context) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 92
> at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view,
> IMauiContext context) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
> at
> Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler
> handler) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line
> 44    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler
> handler, IContentView page) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line
> 49    at
> Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 79    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement element) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:line 129    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView,
> Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup,
> Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
> at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView
> view) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line
> 27    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView,
> Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup,
> Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler
> newHandler) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line
> 69    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler
> value) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line
> 19    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler
> value) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line
> 308    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement
> view, IMauiContext context) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
> at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view,
> IMauiContext context) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
> at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ScopedFragment.OnCreateView(LayoutInflater
> inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\Navigation\ScopedFragment.cs:line
> 22    at
> AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr
> jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_inflater, IntPtr
> native_container, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) in
> C:\a_work\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\net6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:line
> 2031    at
> Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L(_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L
> callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0, IntPtr p1, IntPtr
> p2) in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line
> 352 "

Comment: Please include the relevant code and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What errors do you see? One way to solve this is by removing the other platforms from your MAUI project (i.e. delete their respective folders in the *Platforms* directory and remove their target platform identifiers from the *.csproj* file).

Comment: @Julian I edit the question and added some codes and error details , I will try what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Maps 8.0.3. Downgraded to 7.0.101 and it works. MS should be ashamed of putting out such garbage.